# django POST IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I got an IntegrityError when I POST data at /users/profiles.
I have only one instance in Profile model. And POST another data.
I can not understand why that data exist already..
Here is my code. and I put the trace back after code.
models.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Job(models.Model):
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pk} {self.job_name}'


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone_nm, login_ID, login_PW, age, gender, password):
        if not phone_nm:
            raise ValueError('User must have a phone_nm')
        if not login_ID:
            raise ValueError('User must have an login_ID')
        if not login_PW:
            raise ValueError('User must have a login_PW')
        if not age:
            raise ValueError('User must have an age')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('User must have a password')
        user = self.model(phone_nm=phone_nm, login_ID=login_ID, login_PW=login_PW, age=age, gender=gender, password=password)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = False
        user.is_staff = False
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_nm, login_ID, login_PW, age, gender, password):
        if not phone_nm:
            raise ValueError('User must have a phone_nm')
        if not login_ID:
            raise ValueError('User must have an login_ID')
        if not login_PW:
            raise ValueError('User must have a login_PW')
        if not age:
            raise ValueError('User must have an age')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('User must have a password')
        user = self.create_user(phone_nm, login_ID, login_PW, age, gender, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def get_by_natural_key(self, phone_nm):
        print(phone_nm)
        return self.get(phone_nm=phone_nm)


class User(AbstractUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
        (0, 'Female'),
        (1, 'Male'),
    ]
    phone_nm = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    login_ID = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    login_PW = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    gender = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=False)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['login_ID', 'login_PW', 'age', 'gender']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_nm'

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pk}-{self.phone_nm}'


class Profile(models.Model):
    related_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        related_name='related_user',
                                primary_key=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    introduction = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    jobs = models.ManyToManyField('Job', null=True, blank=True, default=None, related_name='jobs_set') 
    click_recomms = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False,
                                           related_name='get_recomms', blank=True)

    def recomms_cnt(self):
        return self.get_recomms.all().count()


    def already_clicked(self, to_prof): 
        if to_prof in self.click_recomms.all().values_list('pk', flat=True):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pk}-{self.nickname}'

    def get_jobs(self):
        return self.jobs.all().values('id','job_name')
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'phone_nm', 'login_ID', 'login_PW', 'age', 'gender', 'password']


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    jobs = JobSerializer(required=False, many=True, allow_null=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['related_user_id', 'nickname', 'introduction', 'jobs', 'recomms_cnt', 'related_user']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        related_user_data = validated_data.pop('related_user')
        related_user = User.objects.create(**related_user_data)
        jobs_data = validated_data.pop('jobs')
        # job_dic = {'job_name': j.job_name}
        profile = Profile.objects.create(**validated_data,
                                         related_user=related_user)  # Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use jobs.set() instead.
        profile.jobs.add(Job.objects.get(pk=1))
        return profile

    def validate(self, data):  
        if data.get('jobs', None) is None:
            j = Job.objects.get(pk=1)  # 의미없음(nothing)
        return data
```

views.py

```
class ProfileList(APIView):
    # 회원 조회
    def get(self, request):
        # 모든 profile 불러옴. ORM은 .all() 사용
        profiles = Profile.objects.all()
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(profiles, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    # 회원 가입
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=data, partial=True)
        # jobs = serializer.data['jobs']  # list 형태?
        # recomms = serializer.data['recomms'] # list형태?
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            serializer.validate(data)
            serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

traceback:

```
IntegrityError at /users/profiles/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/profiles/
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.

Exception Location: C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 84, in _execute
Python Executable:  C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.9

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\users\views.py", line 51, in post
    serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\users\serializers.py", line 45, in create
    related_user = User.objects.create(**related_user_data)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
 

   self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\github\dj-postgres-heroku\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /users/profiles/
```

Exception Value: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.

Comment: Try inheriting `User` from `AbstractBaseUser`. Let me know if it works, please.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works POST!! but I can't understand the reason.. haha,,,, And,, admin page isn't work.. It said  AttributeError at /admin/
'User' object has no attribute 'is_staff'

Comment: It's all about python inheritance: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/inheritance